# How to send values (Dynamic variables) to external JSON API (Post Method) in Drupal 7?

Tags: json, rest, drupal-7

How to send values (Dynamic variables) to external JSON API (Post Method) in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

$data = array("name" => $name, "desc" => $desc,"email" => $email,"lastname" => $lastname);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://ur);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);